# Rename all files inside subdirectories and place it in their respective parent directory in destination folder

Tags: java, file

I have below folder structure

```
.
└── sample/
    ├── A-Star/
    │   ├── bonnet.png
    │   ├── center of front bumper.png
    │   └── center of rear bumper.png
    ├── Alto/
    │   ├── bonnet.png
    │   ├── center of front bumper.png
    │   └── center of rear bumper.png
    └── Suzuki/
        ├── bonnet.png
        ├── center of front bumper.png
        └── center of rear bumper.png
```

I want to loop directory one by one and then convert the filename into uppercase, for single word like `bonnet.png` it should be `BONNET.png`, but for filename having spaces like  `center of front bumper`, it should be `CENTER_OF_FRONT_BUMPER.png`.

the output should be like below

```
.
└── sample/
    ├── A-Star/
    │   ├── bonnet.png
    │   ├── center of front bumper.png
    │   └── center of rear bumper.png
    ├── Alto/
    │   ├── bonnet.png
    │   ├── center of front bumper.png
    │   └── center of rear bumper.png
    ├── Suzuki/
    │   ├── bonnet.png
    │   ├── center of front bumper.png
    │   └── center of rear bumper.png
    └── output/
        ├── A-Star/
        │   ├── BONNET.png
        │   ├── CENTER_OF_FRONT_BUMPER.png
        │   └── CENTER_OF_REAR_BUMPER.png
        ├── Alto/
        │   ├── BONNET.png
        │   ├── CENTER_OF_FRONT_BUMPER.png
        │   └── CENTER_OF_REAR_BUMPER.png
        └── Suzuki/
            ├── BONNET.png
            ├── CENTER_OF_FRONT_BUMPER.png
            └── CENTER_OF_REAR_BUMPER.png
```

I have written a below code but it is not working as per expectaiton.

firstly it able to make the filename in uppercase(not appended underscore), but it doesn't create the parent directory and without creating the parent directory it copies the files inside that.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Test {
    public void listFiles(String startDir) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File(startDir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File file : files) {
                // Check if the file is a directory
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    // We will not print the directory name, just use it as a new
                    // starting point to list files from
                    listFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
//                    Path source = file.toPath();
//                    Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(file.getName().toUpperCase()));
                } else {
                    String path = "D:" + File.separator + "sample" + File.separator + "After Rename";
                    // Use relative path for Unix systems
                    File f = new File(path);
                    f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
                    f.createNewFile();
           
                    // We can use .length() to get the file size
//                  String DestinationPath="D:\\sample\\After Rename";
                    Path source = file.toPath();
                    File oldFile = new File(source.toString());
                    file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
                    file.createNewFile();
                    file.getName().toUpperCase();
//                    File newFile = new File(path,file);
////                    Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(file.getName().toUpperCase()));
//                    oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
                    System.out.println(""+oldFile.getName());
//                    System.out.println(file.getName() + " (size in bytes: " + file.length()+")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test test = new Test();
        String startDir = ("D:\\sample");
        test.listFiles(startDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly problem you have?

Comment: code able to rename the files and but unable to placed it in proper place using its parent directory

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part of code doesn't work? What is expected behavior? What is observed behavior?

Comment: else part is not working as per expectations
, expected behavior should be go to each directory pick files and rename it and place it in destination, if source path is c:/file/A/bonnet.png, then output should be c:/output/A/BONNET.png, please check the directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `File` and recursive `File.listFiles()` makes the logic harder to follow. Consider switching to `Files.find` which can produce a directory scan with a small amount of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path src = Path.of(args[0]);
    Path dst = Path.of(args[1]);

    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(src, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attr) -> attr.isRegularFile())) {
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The above just prints names of files to process. Then you can swap the action for something that performs the rename, and can be adjusted to apply the action constructing directories before copying:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(src, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attr) -> attr.isRegularFile())) {
    stream.forEach(file -> {
        // Work out new file name converting basename to uppercase:
        String fn = file.getFileName().toString();
        int dot = fn.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (dot > 0)
            fn = fn.substring(0,dot).toUpperCase().replace(' ', '_') + fn.substring(dot);

        // Work out where to copy the new file under the same path of the dst directory:
        Path target = dst.resolve(src.relativize(file)).resolveSibling(fn);
            System.out.println("Files.createDirectories("+target.getParent()+");");
            System.out.println("Files.copy("+file+"," + target+");");
            /**
            // TODO:
            try
            {
                Files.createDirectories(target.getParent());
                Files.copy(file,target);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
             */
    });
}
```

It's never a good idea to generate files into the directory you scan - as that means you cannot re-run on same input as you will be doubling the number of files.

Comment: Could you please post complete snippet for the same

Comment: @jack For the same what? Just remove System.out and call the methods listed: `Files.createDirectories(target.getParent());` and `Files.copy(file,target);` handling exception appropriately

Comment: I mean to say is the posted snippet is enough to achieve my usecase, could you please mimic my directory structure into your local and produce the output

Comment: You just need to pass in 2 arguments to the example `main` I show :- source directory and target directory such as `java YourClass sample output`. I mentioned its better these are independent of each other, and if you run it you'll see what it prints for your data before uncommenting the lines that actually copy the files.

Comment: it is working fine as I am expecting, thank you so much for your kind assitance

Comment: It would be really appreciablem if you will assist me on this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280096/copy-aws-s3-objects-into-db?noredirect=1#comment555027_280096, I have created post in order to optimize one of my code snipped in my codebase, please look into the same and provide your valuable suggestion. thanks

Comment: @jack I've not used S3 services, so not in best position help with that one.

Comment: Its not about S3 services, if you closely observed my post, so its all about refractoring and optimization, my code is working fine, the only problem is three different service layer utilizing the same code, I want to isolate those, that's it, I am looking for a way, where I can extract out the common code in one place and let other services use that common code by passing their own instance. There is nothing to do about S3 in this.